# x86 assembly make a window and set width and height size

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

When making a window using `invoke MessageBox,(string),(string)` syntax, are their any parameters that allow you to set the size of the window you are creating?

For example,

```
.386
.model flat,sdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib 

.data
     msg db "Hello, world!",0
     title db "A messagebox",0
.code 
start:
      invoke MessageBox, NULL,addr title, addr msg, MB_OK
      invoke ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

Is there any way that I can change the size of the box that is made? Like a width/height parameter?

Thanks

Comment: 386 instruction set is long dead - and why even do this the hard way with asm? Time has moved on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you need control over the window, you should make a [DialogBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's quite involved however.

Comment: Could you provide some example assembly code to make a simple dialogbox?

Comment: After having a look, SURELY there must be a simple macro or something to create a window, or at least something simpler??? It's so overly complex!

Comment: I don't have any masm code using dialogs, but perhaps you would be better off making an ordinary window with CreateWindow? It's hard to guess what you need.

Comment: How do I use createwindow? I looked at all the code on the internet and its in C++

Comment: Look it up on msdn. It's similar to making a dialog box.

Comment: Could you show me an example? Sorry to be a bother, but I just don't get how to implement it.

Comment: @AussieGamer - The function [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a monster taking twelve (12) parameters, some of which must first be registered using other calls. There *is* a reason most people don't try to do this in assembly!